# How to run an async task in flask app (Without using Rabbit MQ in Celery)

Tags: python

I just need to run an async task once a route is called. The response should be returned once the task is initiated. How can I do it without using RabbitMQ and Celery in python.

```
@app.route('/preprocess')
def pre_process():
    thr = threading.Thread(target=PreProcessor().initiate_preprocess_task())
thr.start()
return "Pre-process task initiated!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackgroundScheduler and start this task when the route is called and stop it in the background task.

Example of code :

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.add_job(fetch_data_coronavirus, 'interval', minutes=1, id='my_job_id')
# to start the background task
sched.start()
# to stop the background task
sched.remove_job('my_job_id')
```